# can't trace out Reason of Error :_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm getting this error recently , I don't know why its happening also as far as I know I haven't made any recent changes in my ViewController  where error is pointing 
I followed a similar question and according to that question's answer my Framework is not linked into my project correctly, which is not true in my case I double checked it and (framework social & messageUI) strange thing is that this error is only raising when I'm trying to run my project on simulator when I'm running this in a real device its working fine. Anyone faced anything similar ? knows how can I fix this ?? Please let me know then

```
  ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/user1/Desktop/mypackage 2.0/IOS/mypackage/Social.framework/Social.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/user1/Desktop/mypackage 2.0/IOS/mypackage/Social.framework/Social.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.SLComposeViewController in SettingTableViewController.o
  "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
      mypackage.SettingTableViewController.(tableView (__ObjC.UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath : __ObjC.NSIndexPath) -> ()).(closure #4) in SettingTableViewController.o
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      mypackage.SettingTableViewController.(tableView (__ObjC.UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath : __ObjC.NSIndexPath) -> ()).(closure #5) in SettingTableViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my VC where I'm using this social APIs

```
      if indexPath.row == 3 {

        //Create the AlertController
        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Share with your friends", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

        //Create and add the Cancel action
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Just dismiss the action sheet
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
        //Create and add first option action
        let shareEmailAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Email", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in

            // Email Subject
            let emailTitle: String = "Great new tool"
            // Email Content
            let messageBody: String = self.inviteTextBody
            // To address
            let toRecipents: [String] = [""]
            let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
            mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
            // Present mail view controller on screen
            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: { _ in })

            if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
                let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "Mail services are not available, Please try again later.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alertView.show()
                return

            }

        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(shareEmailAction)
        //Create and add a second option action
        let shareWhatsappAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Whatsapp", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in


            let escapedString = self.inviteTextBody.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())


            let whatsappURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(escapedString!)")


            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL!)) {

                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL!)
            }

        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(shareWhatsappAction)


        let shareWithFBAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_setup_provider", sender: self)
            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook){
                let facebookSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
                facebookSheet.setInitialText(self.inviteTextBody)
                self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(shareWithFBAction)

        let shareWithTwitterAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_setup_provider", sender: self)

            if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter){
                let twitterSheet:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
                twitterSheet.setInitialText(self.inviteTextBody)
                self.presentViewController(twitterSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(shareWithTwitterAction)


        let shareWithSMSAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SMS", style: .Default)
        { action -> Void in


            if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
                let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                controller.body = self.inviteTextBody
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
                self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_setup_provider", sender: self)

        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(shareWithSMSAction)

        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        //We need to provide a popover sourceView when using it on iPad
        actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = cell as UIView

        //Present the AlertController
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add Account.framework  and Social.frameworks in your project?

Comment: @Amit89 hey man yes i did and  check the updated question